# VueJS router in hash mode: route to error page if file not found

Tags: vue.js, url-routing, vue-router

I'm having issues with the VueJS Router in hash-mode.

This is what the router config looks like:

```
{
    mode: 'hash',
    base: process.env.BASE_URL,
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            name: 'game',
            component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: 'game-page' */ '@/app/views/GamePage.vue'),
            meta: { title: 'Game', },
        },
        {
            path: '*',
            name: '404',
            component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: '404-page' */ '@/app/views/404Page.vue'),
        },
    ],
}
```

I need to use the hash-mode since I'm developing for Cordova, but now I run into the following:

The * doesn't get matched when there is no # in the url.

In some cases the `beforeEach` is still called so I can work things out myself. For example `http://localhost:8080/audio` triggers the `beforeEach` and I can manually check if window.location is correct.

However, with an url like `http://localhost:8080/audio/some_nonexsisting_file.ogg` the router doesn't do anything (it doesn't call the `beforeEach`) and just shows a blank page.

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Can you show your code for your router? Do you have a catch all in there?

Comment: Post the routes you’ve defined with vue router. You might not have a fallback route in there

Comment: I've clarified the question some more and added the router config

Comment: Is `/audio/music.ogg` a static file?

Comment: @TrevorVarwig The file is not there, so I want an error or a redirect to a 404 page. (clarified the question some more)

Comment: I would assume the webpack dev server is not routing the 404 to vue. To test this can you build your code and copy in nginx or apache and act like production. In nginx I would setup `error_page 404 /#/404;` (this should route to your catch all). If it does work fine in production it will be the webpack dev server, it not there is another issue. Also take a look at  [https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/] (https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/) too for dev server routing

Comment: When I use the Cordova test server it works fine. So it's probably a webpack dev server thing indeed. Question remains if anything can be done about it. At the moment it's quite annoying to spot for example invalid urls being loaded.